# How do I get the date and time from my computer with Autohotkey

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

How do I get the date and time?  The tutorial seems to be a bit wacky.  Basically, I want the date and time to be recorded to a file when I press the button C.  I think the following is correct:

```
    c:: FileAppend,
    (
    *However you do date and time
    ), C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\times.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
  ^#C::
   FormatTime, TimeString, %A_NOW%, MMMM d, yyyy
   Send, %TimeString%
   return
```

adapted from [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/65320-paste-clipboard-script/#entry412461)

Comment: or see http://superuser.com/questions/241050/automatic-insertion-of-current-date-and-time-in-alphabetic-form